# Terminal.com snaps are sunsetting - are there any alternatives?

Tags: cloud-service, hosted

[terminal.com is sunsetting their public snaps infrastructure](http://blog.terminal.com/next-up-for-terminal-com/)

It was super nice to be able to spin up a snapshot, do some development, and then shut it down, and not get charged when it was off.

Is there any alternative company that provides a similar solution?  Obviously there are virtual hosts like DigitalOcean, Linode, and others, but they charge whether your VM is on or off.

At one point they showed that if you turned your VM on and used it for development, and turned it off at the end of the workday (i.e. 40 hours a week) you'd end out only spending $9/yr, which is quite a bit cheaper than the $60/yr you'll pay to have something like a digital ocean droplet around the whole year.

Are there any alternatives to Terminal.com that provide the same kind of pricing and resources?

Comment: Please add some examples of your usage scenarios - are you needing the scale-able side for big data sets, the collaboration side or both? Which languages/tools are you primarily focused on?

Comment: my provided examples is what I'm mostly interested in